# On my Careers 2.0 profile, how should I add skills I've learned from a propriety hobby project I'm working on?

Tags: support, jobs

I've been working on a hobby project after work and I've been learning a lot of new skills from it.  But the "likes" text field has run out of space and this project is (temporarily?) closed source so I can't add these skills as a github repo.  Where should I put these new skills?  I'd like employers to know I can use these technologies even though I've never been paid to use them.

Here's an idea: I could add this as experience that overlaps the time span of my current job.  But I'm not sure if this is the type of thing I'm supposed to add to that "Experience" section.

Comment: The "Apps & Software" section is a good place for side projects that aren't really work experience. You can put technologies there, and they will show up in employer searches.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a judgment call. Since you say you don't have room for more likes, maybe you should consider only listing the ones which interest you most. A concise list of your interests is better than a rambling list of every technology you've ever touched.

If you have a substantial non-work project, then I think it's perfectly fine to make an experience section for it, but remember that most programmers play around with projects/technologies in their off time. So an entry just to point out that you dabble is probably counter-productive.

Ideally, though, you should find one of your projects to open source. Examples of open source will go a lot further towards making your profile appealing to employers than either of the first two options (showing is better than telling). Ultimately that's the point of Careers 2.0 anyway - employers can look at your stackoverflow answers and open source projects, rather than just taking your word for it.